# Closing Network Sockets

Tags: networking, windows-10

I was practicing using TCP connections in C# but I was stupid and never closed my sockets after I was done.

Now I have about two hundred sockets open on my loopback.

How can I close these without restarting my PC?
They are all listed under the System Image in the resource monitor.
[loopback connector list shown as proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTaXW.png)

Comment: When the process closed those sockets were closed.  A socket cannot remain open without a process

Comment: They are running under the system process. See the picture.

Comment: you can log in and out of the user profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets usually do not remain open when there is no process. In this situation, you could kill all the processes by simply running the following command in an elevated command prompt (except that the process is running under system account and you may not be able to kill it by using the ordinary cmd.exe).

To get the list of tasks, run the following command:
tasklist /fi "PID eq 4"

To kill the processes:
taskkill /pid 4 /f /t

If access is denied, you need to work a bit more to terminate the system processes. I use SysInternals PsExec.

1. Download PsExec from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx).
2. Open up an elevated command prompt and navigate to the extracted PsTools folder. Use CD command to navigate.
3. Run the following command: PSEXEC -i -s -d CMD
4. Now you have opened up a cmd.exe with the system privileges. You can verify it with task manager.
5. Now you can execute the commands I provided earlier successfully.